# Conditional Formatting based on a dropdown in another sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a Query function in Sheet2 which is based on a dropdown selection in cell I11 of Sheet1. In the Sheet2 Query, I want to automatically highlight the name selected in the Sheet1 dropdown. Per my example below, if 'New Zealand' is selected in the dropdown I want New Zealand to be highlighted like this:

[image]

I have tried MATCH, EXACT, INDIRECT and combinations of these but cannot get any to work. I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on range **A2:F** use this custom formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A2, INDIRECT("Sheet1!I11"))
```

or:

```
=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A2), LOWER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!I11")))
```